# How to extract variable from jmeter selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, webdriver

I have a token thats being returned in the body.

```html
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//*[contains(@name,'RequestVerificationToken')]")).getText();
```

This is the token I'm trying to extract:

[image]

Now what im trying to do is to pass that variable out of the selenium webdriver to the rest of the threads.

Usually when im working with normal pages I go for regular expression extractor as a post processor and set to a variable then correlate it but Im not sure where to go here.

How do I make it a global variable in JS?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the complete value of the *`name`* attribute. Additionally, the *`token`* is actually the ***value*** attribute, so you have to use `getAttribute("value")` instead as follows:

```
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//input[@name='__RequestVerificationToken']")).getAttribute("value");
```

Comment: thank you for your comment. now how do i export it to be a global variable to be called in the following samples?

Comment: @MohammadOtoum Sounds to be a different question all together. Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement.

Comment: its literally the last statement in my post... what was before it is describing :D im asking how can i export a variable to be a global variable to be used by other samples

Answer (score 0):

The element you want to interact with doesn't have text, what you need is [`value` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_value.asp) so you need to amend your code as:

```
var token = WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//*[contains(@name,'RequestVerificationToken')]")).getAttribute('value')
```

If you want to share this token with all threads in this or other Thread Groups you can save it into a [JMeter Property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) like:

```
WDS.props.put('token', token)
```

so in other WebDriver Samplers instances you will be able to access it as:

```
var token = WDS.props.get('token')
```

and in other JMeter test elements it will be possible to use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like:

```
${__P(token,)}
```

More information: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered)

Comment: Thank you sir it worked! i appreciate your support